# NuxtJs publicRuntimeConfig in typescript plugin

Tags: typescript, plugins, nuxtjs

i'm trying to use public publicRuntimeConfig inside a TypeScript plugin with no success. With JS plugins i have no problems. But now i'm really stuck, i think i don't look at the right place.

The question is how can i access to this config in a TypeScript plugin ?

Here's my nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
    ssr: false,
    ...
    
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
    },
}
```

My plugin :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Configuration, FolderApi, Folder } from '~/build/openapi/index'
import { AbstractApi } from '~/plugins/api/abstractApi'
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {

    interface Vue {
        $RfolderApi: MyFolderApi
    }
}

export class MyFolderApi extends AbstractApi {
    private folderApi: FolderApi

    constructor() {
        super()
        // How to access to app.$config ? Of course they are undefined in this example... What to do to import it ?
        this.folderApi = new FolderApi(new Configuration({}), app.$config.baseURL) 
    }
    
    ...
}

Vue.prototype.$RfolderApi = new MyFolderApi()
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of "no success" are you getting: error(s) from TypeScript compilation? runtime JavaScript error(s)? incorrect behavior? Please add that to the question.

Comment: Hello @kdau, i have no ideas on how i can access to app.$config.baseURL. Of course app and $config are undefined because they must come from somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuxt makes the `$config` available in two ways: as `this.$config` on every component instance, and `context.$config` passed to "special nuxt lifecycle areas like `asyncData`, `fetch`, `plugins`, `middleware` and `nuxtServerInit`" ([docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context)).

It looks like you need to access the `$config` outside a component, so you'll need to retrieve it early in the request cycle. In particular, since you're mutating the `Vue.prototype`, this feels like a good fit for a [plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins) in the Nuxt sense, which isn't quite what you've got in your code.

If you put your plugin file in the `plugins` directory and reference it from the `plugins` array in `nuxt.config.js` (see link above for a broader example), you could rewrite it like this to access `$config`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Configuration, FolderApi, Folder } from '~/build/openapi/index'
import { AbstractApi } from '~/plugins/api/abstractApi'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $RfolderApi: MyFolderApi
    }
}

export class MyFolderApi extends AbstractApi {
    private folderApi: FolderApi

    constructor(baseURL: string) {
        super()
        this.folderApi = new FolderApi(new Configuration({}), baseURL) 
    }
    
    // ...
}

export default function({ $config }) {
  Vue.prototype.$RfolderApi = new MyFolderApi($config.baseURL)
}
```

The `$config` object's type declaration (`NuxtRuntimeConfig`) has its values typed as `any`, so that code will work as is, but you could also extend the declaration to make your property explicit like so:

```
declare module '@nuxt/types/config/runtime'
{
    interface NuxtRuntimeConfig
    {
        baseURL: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @kdau, it's exactly what i was looking for.